# Solution of a second order Stochastic Differential Equation

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis

Consider the following SDE:

$$dx = (-ax)dt + \sigma db\\
dy = (-by+e^{-x})dt$$

where $a,b,\sigma>0$ and $b$ is a Brownian motion.

PROBLEM: What is the solution of this system? How can I estimate the variance and expected value of $y$?

I not sure if I should solve the first equation for $x$ and then solve the second one;

$$x(t) = e^{-at}x(0)+\int\limits_{0}^{t}{e^{-a(t-s)}db_s}$$

Answer (score 2):

Yes it's good start! Once we solved the Ornstein Ulenbeck process $x_t$. We then solve the ODE on $y$. Let suppose that we have no 2nd member first. We solve the homogeneous ode: 
$dy_t = -by_tdt$ where an obvious solution is $y_t = C_t\exp(-bt)$.

Now we will use the variation parameter method. To do so, we apply the integration by part:
\begin{align*}
dy_t &= \exp(-bt)dC_t -b\exp(-bt)C_tdt \\
-by_tdt + \exp(-x_t)dt &= \exp(-bt)dC_t -b\exp(-bt)C_tdt \\
dC_t = \exp(b_t-x_t)dt
\end{align*}
Knowning that $C_0 = y_0$, we have: $C_t = y_0 + \int_0^t \exp(bs - x_s)ds$. Thus, 
\begin{equation*}
y_t = y_0\exp(-bt) + \int_0^t \exp(-b(t-s) - x_s)ds
\end{equation*}
The second part of your question is to compute the expectation and the variance of $y$ for any $t$. Bear in mind that the stochastic integral in $x$, i.e. $\int_0^te^{-a(t-s)}db_s$, is a Wiener process. It follows a centered Gaussian variable with variance $\int_0^te^{-2a(t-s)}ds$. Then $x_t \sim \mathcal{N}(e^{-at}x_0, \int_0^te^{-2a(t-s)}ds)$. Now that we know the distribution of $x$ computing the expectation and the variance of $y$ is very simple. 
\begin{align*}
\forall t\in R_+, m_t = E[y_t] &= e^{-bt}y_0 + E[\int_0^t \exp(-b(t-s) - x_s)ds] \\
&= e^{-bt}y_0 + \int_0^t\exp(-b(t-s))E[\exp(- x_s)]ds \quad \text{Fubini-Tonelli}  \\
&=  e^{-bt}y_0 + \int_0^t\exp\left(-b(t-s) - e^{-as}x_0 + \frac12\int_0^s e^{-2a(s-u)}du\right)ds 
\end{align*}
For the variance, we calculate:
\begin{equation*}
Var(y_t) = E\left[\left(\int_0^t \exp(-b(t-s) - x_s)ds\right)^2\right] - (m_t)^2
\end{equation*}
I will let you finish the computation. (Hint :We still need to use Fubini in order to bring the expectation inside of the integral and differentate all the cases).